# To which module do __getitem__ and __len__ pertain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

While trying to understand "magic" or special methods on python, and reading [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), I was under the impression that any object would have those methods.

If we do something simple like

```
class ClassicSpam:
    pass

dir(ClassicSpam())
```

I get something like:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__']
```

I am trying to understand how does this work, from the point of view of classes and inheritance.

What is making that any call that fulfills this contract `self[key]` we "know" internally is going to call `object.__getitem__(self, key)`

Maybe this is not the right approach, and I am thinking too "java-like", but I would like to understand what am I missing and what happens when I implement __getitem__ in a class I implement.

Comment: Partial explanation: the [`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f185a73249189bc3b75b4dc26e9ec2990a587b17/Python/ceval.c#L1577) bytecode instruction is responsible for evaluating an expression like `a[b]`. It calls [PyObject_GetItem](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d33e46d17d33f9b918846982c02ddc17d897c9bc/Objects/abstract.c#L143), which (among other things) examines the object's type and MRO to determine whether it has a `__getitem__` method that it can call. Most double-underscore methods are invoked in similar ways.

Comment: Why do you think `object.__getitem__` will be called? `object` doesn't define `__getitem__`, so any attempt to index a class which doesn't define or inherit `__getitem__` will raise a `TypeError` rather than call `object.__getitem__` (unless you misuse `super`).

Comment: There are two ways to look at your question. If you're asking *how* does `self[key]` "knows" how to call `self.__getitem__(key)`, it's because that's how Python's implementation (in C) works. If you're asking *why* does it do that, it's because one of the core strengths of Python is being able to define low-level methods and automatically take advantage of the high-level syntax of the language: `__iter__` -> `for thing in self:`, `__getitem__` -> `self[thing]`, etc.

Comment: (Or are you using `object` generically? There is a predefined class `object` in Python, which serves as the ultimate parent class for every type.)

Comment: Ultimately, it's an implementation detail. Python-the-language just defines that `foo[x]` is equivalent to `type(foo).__getitem__(foo, x)` without specifying *how* that equivalence is implemented.

Comment: to both @kevin and jfaccioni, thank you very much for your answers, I feel you could post as an answer instead of a comment, they are very helpful!

Comment: @chepner I fell under that impression because when reading the official documentation it explictly defines "object.__getitem__(self, key)", so I mistakenly thought it was the object used in inheritance, and not a generic object, and then I realized, if object is not the class that holds the method, how is this working

Comment: Ah, never noticed that. Yeah, the documentation is using `object` (and `class`, for class methods) generically for any object that *could* implement a method, whether or not the actually class `object` does so.